# Unused Ram in PostgreSQL Database Server

Tags: postgresql, memory, memory-management

What is "unused RAM" in the PostgreSQL database server?

For example, with a PostgreSQL database server with 120 GB, shared_buffers is 30 GB, work_mem 500 MB and *max_connections* is 100. If all the sessions utilize all of the work_mem (let' s assume we do not use hash_multiplier due to has join), so in that case 30 GB + (500 MB * 100) = 80 GB. For those processes spill to disk will use local temporary areas, but what happens to that 40 GB?

Comment: Do you mean https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/111195/postgresql-doesnt-use-all-the-ram-it-could ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot calculate like this. Not every session uses `work_mem`, and a single session may use multiple times that amount of memory.

There are two things you have to distinguish: truly *unused memory* and *available memory*. You can see that in the output of `free` on Linux:

```
free -m
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15792        3391        7734         912        4666       11305
Swap:          16183           0       16183
```

Here, 3391 MB are used by processes, 912 MB are allocated as shared memory, 7734 MB are unused and 4666 are used to cache files. Together, there are 11305 MB that can be freed by the operating system if a process needs more memory.

On a busy system, unused memory is usually very low. You have to make sure that there is always enough available memory, so that you don't go out of memory. On a PostgreSQL machine, "buff/cache" will cache database files, so it is memory that is used to cache PostgreSQL.

Comment: This kind of configuration is completely fine for OLTP databases, but, to be honest, I don' t this kind of configuration for OLAP databases. Why would I give away 40 GB? For OS, I could save %20, so 24 GB, for `shared_buffers = 72 GB` and for the queries I can set `work_mem=24 GB/100(max_connecetions) -> ~240MB`. Therefore, heavily queries end up with local SSDs. Does not make sense to minimize `unused memory`?

Comment: Also, you said in the post `Don't set it to 60GB (half your RAM) to avoid double buffering.` Why do we avoid double buffering? I believe it is one of useful concepts in the database systems.

Comment: Unused memory is always small anyway (unless you just freed a bunch of memory). There is nothing you have to do about it. I fail to understand your problem.

Comment: I think we do not mean same thing with [double buffering](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/double-buffering/). After checking caching the same thing on the OS filesystem cache and on the database shared buffers, I got what you mean. Things are clear now :).